# Clojure JDBC - This ResultSet is closed

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, clojure

I am currently learning using Clojure and connection with postgresql and I am stuck. In my code, I can successfully query using `SELECT` using `java.jdbc` dependency but got an exception when I `UPDATE` or `INSERT`

I am using these dependencies

```
[org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.7.8"]
[postgresql "9.3-1102.jdbc41"]
```

This is my working code for `SELECT`-ing from a table called `public."user"`

```
(ns knp-api.model.user
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as sql]))


(def db "jdbc:postgresql://ampersanda@localhost:5432/idjoesoft_klinik")

(defn get-count [q]
  "Get count key from query
   It takes jdbc.query as parameter"
  (:count (first (into [] q))))

(defn is-user-email-available? [e]
  "Returns boolean when email is available.
   Take one parameter, it's email"
  (let [q "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.\"user\" t WHERE user_email = ?"]
    (sql/query db [q e] {:result-set-fn #(= 1 (get-count %))})))
```

and this is not my code which makes an exception appear

```
(defn set-user-timestamp-and-token [email token timestamp]
  "update user current token and last login time inside database.
   Takes email, token, and current timestamp as parameter"
  (sql/update! db 
               "public.\"user\"" 
               {:user_last_login (str "to_timestamp(" timestamp ")") 
                :user_token token}  
               ["user_email = ?" email]))
```

and this is the exception

[image]

**UPDATE**

I also try using REPL to create table and I also get the same results.

```
knp-api.handler=> (require '[clojure.java.jdbc :as sql])
nil
knp-api.handler=> (sql/db-do-commands "jdbc:postgresql://ampersanda@localhost:5432/idjoesoft_klinik" (sql/create-table-ddl :testing [[:data :text]]))

PSQLException This ResultSet is closed.  org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkClosed (AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2852)
```

Comment: The error itself occurs if a result set is used after it has been closed. This can for example happen if in autocommit mode you execute multiple interleaved statements. You're also using a pretty old version of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Any recommendation for PostgreSQL JDBC driver? I followed this steps from Heroku.

Comment: @MochamadLuckyPradana : Any luck with this?

Comment: @Ashwin: Unfortunately, no :(, I use `funcool/clojure.jdbc` instead

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the update is happening fine, and then it's trying to return the rows that changed, and it's trying to do so as a lazy sequence. the thing that tries to print/process that lazy sequence of results may be doing so after the connection is closed.

try wrapping the select statement in a call to `doall` to ensure that it's read immediately and not allowed to be a lazy database.

Comment: So, I tried wrapping my SELECT query with `doall`, inside of my `is-user-email-available?` function, but I got an different error says that `Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Boolean`. This function should return boolean, so I change my code to

`(let [q "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.\"user\" t WHERE user_email = ?"]
    (= 1 (first (doall (map :count (sql/query db [q e]))))))`

which successfully returns boolean, but when I execute the `update` query, it still the same error about ResultSet is empty

Comment: Thanks for checking, this is a common error, and I'll leave it here for others with similar cases, though it does not seem to be the answer to your problem. If you don't get a proper answer in a couple more days I'll put a bounty on the question to try and get more attention.

Comment: I'll keep trying to search the answer and I will update if I figure something. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Having run into the same issue today, the root cause is the postgresql java driver.
`postgresql "9.3-1102.jdbc41"` is five years old, after upgrading to 42.2.6 the issue went away.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I remember having this problem, but it's many years ago and I can't remember the solution. However, wrapping raw JDBC in Clojure is not a good idea. There are a number of excellent Clojure libraries which make working with databases much easier. I'd particularly recomment [SQL Korma](http://www.sqlkorma.com/) and [Hug SQL](https://www.hugsql.org/).

Comment: stay away from Korma! It's buggy and unmaintained. Look at the project's github issues yourself

Answer (score 0):

Having spent a while trying to get this solved I can confirm in my case updating the postgresql java driver solved this issue, if anybody is having the same issue try to use the newest driver from clojars/maven, Clojars even has a message telling you that you should use the version from maven central.